# Address verification and multi step modal dialogue

Tags: modal-windows

We are designing an interface where the user navigates to a page where s/he is presented with a grid of existing business profile data (e.g. business name, address, website, etc).

When the user wants to add a new business, s/he clicks an icon and is presented with a modal dialogue form. After completing the business profile and clicking "Save", we want to perform address verification (i.e. call a service to return a potentially more accurate address than the one the user entered). The user would then be faced with three choices:

1. Keep the address s/he entered.
2. Choose the address provided by the verification service.
3. Enter a new address.

According to [THIS](https://uxplanet.org/5-essential-ux-rules-for-dialog-design-4de258c22116) article which appeared in a similar thread, it is best to avoid multi-step modal dialogues.

Our constraints:

- Modal dialogue must be used for adding the business profile.
- Predictive search for address is not an option. The user must complete traditional address fields and submit.

Our proposed solution (ignoring the article's recommendation) is to implement a modal dialogue with two steps. Upon completion of the first step, the user would be taken to the second step where only the address verification is presented.

Are there any 'better' design alternatives in this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: How many addresses verification service returns - one or more? How many traditional address field do you expect verification service will correct - house, street, city, country?

Comment: The verification service will either return 0 or 1 address. We currently use the address verification in another feature and it corrects:

- Street line one
- Street line two
- City
- State
- ZIP Code (including extension)

Comment: I think your proposed solution is good. Doing so you can keep your profile form clear and simple. Pressing _Save_ in fact is as pressing _Next step_. Then depending on verification result you may step to _Finish_ screen or to address screen with _Back_, _Keep_, _Update_ functions and then to _Finish_ if not back. Just like a kind of step-by-step wizard.